# Runtime polymorphism while creating base class object

Tags: java

Please consider the following code.

```
class Base{
  Base() {  
      print();   
  }
  void print() { 
      System.out.println("Base"); 
  }
}

class Child extends Base{
   int i =   4;
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Base base = new Child();
      base.print();
   }
   void print() { 
       System.out.println(i); 
   }
}
```

The program will print 0,4.

What I understand by this is, the method to be executed will be selected depending on the class of the actual object so in this case is `Child`. So when `Base`'s constructor is called print method of `Child` is called so this will print 0,4.

Please tell if I understood this correctly?
If yes, I have one more question, while Base class constructor is running how come JVM can call `Child`'s method since `Child`'s object is not created?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [...] the method to be executed will be selected depending on the class of the actual object

Yes, your understanding is correct: the method is selected based on the type of the object being created, so the call is sent to `Child.print()` rather than `Base.print()`.

> while `Base` class constructor is running how come JVM can call `Child`'s method since `Child`'s object is not created?

When `Base`'s constructor is running, `Child` object is already *created*. However, it is not fully *initialized*. That is precisely the reason to avoid making calls to methods that can have overrides from inside a constructor: the language allows it, but programmers should take extreme care when doing it.

See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3404301/335858) for more information on problems that may happen when base class constructors call overridable methods.

Comment: good point, creation vs initialization. I used to get confused with this before.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks for clearing that up and the link was useful.

Answer (score 1):

> the method to be executed will be selected depending on the class of the actual object

yes that is correct.

> Base base = new Child();

. It doesn't happen the way you think `while Base class constructor is running how come JVM can call Child's method since Child's object is not created?` it happens. 
Here what happens is, Child instance is created, and while Child instance is being created through default constructor of Child, it first calls the super constructor `that is where the 0 get printed`